# Remove front and end white space from a string

Tags: php

I see this question has been asked a few times but I couldn't find an answer in php.

I have the following string.

```
$myString = "‍ LLC."
```

I run this `trim($myString)`;
and I get this back `"‍ LLC."`
according to the trim documentation it should delete the white space in the front and the back?  What am I missing?

I also tried htis `trim($myString, " ");`  same results

Comment: What does `echo bin2hex($myString);` output?

Comment: This "e2808d20202020202020202020202020204c4c43" when I check it in string it reveals this "â              LLC" . @revo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `e2808d` at the beginning of `bin2hex()` output is `ZERO WIDTH JOINER` character and the reason for `trim()` to not trim it. Try (PHP 7):

```
echo trim($myString, "\u{200d} \t\n\r\0\x0B");
```

Comment: Would this still pick up any white spaces in beginning and ending of string?  I am pulling some data from an api and sometimes it is just blank space in front and end and sometimes it's like this I need to catch both scenerios.  @revo

Comment: It just trims the specified characters. I included the default escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because of the empty space is not really a real white space (tab) looks like a hidden character (â). i copy your variable and value code into an [online PHP editor](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) and i got this:

[image]

Comment: I also see that now I get this "â"  so how do I remove it? @Yassine

Comment: Why you don't just change it to a real white space?

Comment: Cause if it was an isolated one time thing I would have just done it.  You think I'm going to put a question on stack just to ask about " LLC" one time?  @Yassine Qoraiche